# running a Gulp task from .NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, sass, gulp

Is it possible to run a gulp task from C# at runtime? Specifically in a controller action of an MVC application.

I've got user managed content in a cms app, which currently consists of css and js. I'm looking for a way of allowing the user to enter scss, and compile it into css (and minify it) before saving.

I've looked at the BundleTransformer project, which extends the existing System.Web.Optimization library to include SCSS processing in bundles.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.SassAndScss/
http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/

But I'd much prefer to pre-compile the scss whenever it is edited and saved, rather than bundling it when accessed later in a http request (I know the output can be cached, but I'm also hoping to avoid the Bundling query strings eg: "/bundles/my-styles.css?v=592TjSpNmN0TzLFN9wZdSa_yD5-i1nCJTIqWDXaLeCk1").

I'm using gulp locally in my visual studio solution to concat and minify my js and scss resources, and would like to leverage the same functionality if possible.

I can't find any resources on using gulps tasks at runtime.

Perhaps I'm taking the wrong approach, so any alternatives suggestions would be also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Its simple - use the [Process.Start() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("gulp", "taskName");
```

But I think you are probably asking the wrong question. Gulp runs on top of Node.js, and pretty much every one of the extensions in Gulp are wrappers for Node.js applications.

What you should really be asking is "how to run Node.js and .NET code together?" Although I have never used it, a way that looks promising is to use [Edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge).

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EdgeJs;

class Program
{
    public static async void Start()
    {
        var func = Edge.Func(@"
            return function (data, callback) {
                callback(null, 'Node.js welcomes ' + data);
            }
        ");

        Console.WriteLine(await func(".NET"));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run((Action)Start).Wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @NightOwl888, I'm looking into Edge.js